# Adding row to .csv file in python when using mpiexec

Tags: python, csv

The following python3 code creates a .csv file and iteratively adds data in new rows:

```
import csv 

with open('mydata.csv', 'w') as f:
    header = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3']
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)

for i in range(4):
    with open('mydata.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([i, 2*i, i**2])
```

This code works fine when saved as toyexample.py and executed as

```
python toyexample.py
```

However, when executed in parallel as follows,

```
mpiexec -n 4 python toyexample.py
```

Each row is created 4 times! Is there a simple way to iteratively create a .csv file row-by-row when running a python script in parallel? I would prefer to create the file incrementally at each iteration of the for loop if possible.